# Getting puppetlabs-apt module apt::ppa working in puppet hiera

Tags: puppet, hiera

I'm using the puppetlabs-apt forge module together with hiera in puppet 3.8.5.

Adding apt::sources works:

```
apt::sources:
  'ubuntu':
    location: 'http://server.com/ubuntu'
    release: "%{::lsbdistcodename}"
    repos: 'main restricted universe multiverse'
```

... but so far I haven't been able to figure out how to add apt::ppa's to the hiera yaml.

I have tried:

```
apt::ppa:
   'ppa:webupd8team/java':
     ensure: 'present'
```

... and:

```
apt::ppa:'ppa:webupd8team/java'::ensure: 'present'
```

...  but no luck.

Has anybody else got this working?

Comment: I have found that `apt::ppa` only works within a manifest if you first `include ::apt`. For that reason, I doubt it will work in `hiera` like this and I would consider it a flaw/bug in the module.

Answer (score 0):

For those (like me) who found this while googling;

```
apt::ppa:
  'ppa:webupd8team/java':
    ensure: 'present'
```

now works.
( Puppet 4.10, hiera 5, puppetlabs/apt v1.4.0 )

Comment: If you found that elsewhere in a search, consider also including a link to the source.  Welcome to ServerFault!

Comment: A coworker of mine came to this conclusion using trial-and-error, but I'll make sure to keep that in mind !